# TypeError in HTML scraper Python. AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror, nonetype

I keep getting the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text':

`converted_price = float(price[1:5])`
I can't seem to find the problem.
I'm trying to build a HTML scraper that can tell me when a certain product drops to a price under a certain value. I then want it to send me an Email.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib

URL = 'https://www.amazon.de/Toilettendeckel-Absenkautomatik-Antibakterieller-Urea-Duroplast-Edelstahlscharnier/dp/B0881PKQ2H/?_encoding=UTF8&smid=AKQL6N75FLK4O&pd_rd_w=hTIPC&pf_rd_p=d051a36d-9331-41c8-9203-e7d634b1ee23&pf_rd_r=3TS01EKWNMYSRC1147X1&pd_rd_r=d950f9b1-8e9a-4913-b266-9b7a36ad21f5&pd_rd_wg=GLsoO&ref_=pd_gw_unk'

headers = {"User-agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'}

def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')   

    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_saleprice").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price[1:5])

    if converted_price < 40.99:
        send_mail()

    print(converted_price)
    print(title.strip())

    if converted_price > 40.99:
        send_mail()

def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('myemail@gmail.com', 'MyGoogleAppPassword')

    subject = 'Price fell down!'
    body = 'https://www.amazon.de/Toilettendeckel-Absenkautomatik-Antibakterieller-Urea-Duroplast-Edelstahlscharnier/dp/B0881PKQ2H/?_encoding=UTF8&smid=AKQL6N75FLK4O&pd_rd_w=hTIPC&pf_rd_p=d051a36d-9331-41c8-9203-e7d634b1ee23&pf_rd_r=3TS01EKWNMYSRC1147X1&pd_rd_r=d950f9b1-8e9a-4913-b266-9b7a36ad21f5&pd_rd_wg=GLsoO&ref_=pd_gw_unk'

    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail(
        'example@mail.com',
        'anotherexample@mail.com',
        msg
    )
    print('Email has been sent!')

    server.quit()


check_price()
```

Comment: Well that just means soup didn't find `priceblock_saleprice`

Comment: BTW: you can reduce product links, see https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0881PKQ2H

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0):

### Error checking

You should really check for `None` results, see [beautiful documentation of find()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

> If find() can’t find anything, it returns None

[None](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None) itself represents the absence of a value. It therefore has also no attributes. Try `None.get_text()` in the python console to get the exact same message as in your question.

of directly accessing elements in the hoped-for HTML output, take a look on **the big picture**! Use `print(soup)`, the output is even easier to read if you redirect it into an HTML file. Firefox will render it like this:

### Amazon on bots

[image]

We see that in above case, it seems not too hard for amazon to detect that the access is not done by a human (perhaps caused by a large number of consecutive attempts by you or people on StackOverflow trying to reconstruct your problem) and it reacts accordingly.

In the source code, you'll find an informative comment (slightly reformatted):

> To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
> For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at
> `https://developer.amazonservices.de/ref=rm_c_sv`, or our Product Advertising API at
> `https://partnernet.amazon.de/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_c_ac` for advertising use cases.

### Note on tutorials

The video tutorial you mentioned ([Build A Python App That Tracks Amazon Prices!](https://youtu.be/Bg9r_yLk7VY)) has a lot of interesting comments telling what "works" and how to change what "not works". It's not hard to get the idea that the **quality of this tutorial is oscillating** and that's because suspicious requests (same page, same IP, same user-client signature) can trigger counter-measures to prevent [DoS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack).

You should as well consider searching for a better tutorial. I'd suggest [Python Tutorial: Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup and Requests](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng2o98k983k) which starts with first things first. Corey Schafer is not only an expert in what he is teaching, most of his videos are also very focused and dense, so having a finger near the space bar proved to be useful for me.

Answer (score -2):

This was relevant to the original question asked. It is no longer relevant after the many substantial edits made to the question.

The line above should be changed to:

```py
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_saleprice").get_text()
```

You just forgot the parentheses at the end of `get_text`

Comment: Did you print the output of  ```soup```? It appears you can't scrape the site without changing your headers somehow or using something like selenium

Comment: This is not your fault, but after the update to [revision #4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65818634/4) , this answer has completely lost its value.

Comment: Yup, completely changed the question. Should have posted a new one.

Comment: @goalie1998 this is not true. The error described occurs *before* the an opening parenthesis is missed: right after the dot. therefore it would have been better as a comment. In your place, I'd think about retracting it.

Comment: The original question: ```TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable error at this line: converted_price = float(price[1:5])``` . Your code tried to get elements from a method ```get_text```, which is what caused the specific error.

Comment: Oh yes, this is a really strange question. It is a bit like the tutorial itself ([Build A Python App That Tracks Amazon Prices! - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bg9r_yLk7VY&list=LL&index=2&t=265s)) -- the more popularity it gets the more likely it *doesn't work*, see the comments there.